# How to make Hadoop Distcp copy custom list of folders?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, distributed-computing

**I'm looking for efficient way to sync list of directories from one Hadoop filesytem to another with same directory structure.**

For example lets say HDFS1 is official source where data is created and once a week we need to copy newly created data under all **data-2** directories to HDFS2:

```
**HDFS1**
hdfs://namenode1:port/repo/area-1/data-1
hdfs://namenode1:port/repo/area-1/data-2
hdfs://namenode1:port/repo/area-1/data-3
hdfs://namenode1:port/repo/area-2/data-1
hdfs://namenode1:port/repo/area-2/data-2
hdfs://namenode1:port/repo/area-3/data-1

**HDFS2** (subset of HDFS1 - only data-2)
hdfs://namenode2:port/repo/area-1/dir2
hdfs://namenode2:port/repo/area-2/dir2
```

In this case we have 2 directories to sync:

```
/repo/area-1/data-2
/repo/area-1/data-2
```

This can be done by:

```
hadoop distcp hdfs://namenode1:port/repo/area-1/data-2 hdfs://namenode2:port/repo/area-1
hadoop distcp hdfs://namenode1:port/repo/area-2/data-2 hdfs://namenode2:port/repo/area-2
```

*This will run 2 Hadoop jobs, and if number of directories is big, let's say 500 different non overlapping directories under hdfs://namenode1:port/ - this will create 500 Hadoop jobs which is obvious overkill.*

**Is there a way to inject custom directory list into distcp?
How to make distcp create one job copying all paths in custom list of directories?**

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this answers the problem, but I noticed you haven't used the "update" operator. The "-update" operator will only copy over the difference in the blocks between the two file systems...

Comment: thank for contribution, but how to avoid calling many hadoop jobs?